# Asp.net best way to store auth token server side in multiple server system

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, bearer-token

I consume a web service in an asp.net application. This web service has token based authentication that has 10 hours lifetime. I store authentication token in HttpRuntime cache. The problem occurs when I run my application on 2 or more servers concurrently since every server has its own cache.

What is the best way to store token, should I get new token in every request?

Comment: And each server cannot use its own token? Why you need to share it?

Comment: There is 1 user/password. When I call login method in server#2, previous token becomes invalid. Server#1 calls the service with old token.

Comment: That's quite unusual token based authentication. Then maybe you can use distributed cache (like memcached)? Though doing that just for this looks like an overkill, but if that might be useful for other purposes - why not.

Comment: Your answer made me check again, you are right, it's unusual. Old token still working when I get new token. Sorry for taking your time. Thanks a lot.